# External Link Warning for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am looking for a solution to warn our Internal SharePoint Online users that they are leaving our Intranet if they click on a link that is not on our Internal network.

For example, a link to google. User clicks on link, and it typically opens in a new tab.  I want to latch onto this process and insert a message like "You are about to visit an external website. We cannot guarantee the accuracy of this information ... blah blah blah" on every link outside our organization.

I have found information for on-premise installations, but not sure how to do this in SharePoint Online.  Any ideas?

I'm sure this questions exists, but for the life of me, I cannot locate it.  Maybe a keywords issue on my end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the feature called Safe Links which the protection is available in Email messages or Teams and office 365 apps(include SharePoint online).

More information for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/safe-links?view=o365-worldwide

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/configure-global-settings-for-safe-links?view=o365-worldwide